# Alternate word/phrase for "everything is up for debate"

Tags: phrases, synonyms

Is there a synonym to the phrase (if 'synonym phrases' are a thing) "everything will be up for debate" ?

That phrase is commonly used in a collaborative sense, for example - maybe a business owner is creating a new building for his/her company and the design and layout is all open for feedback to the company's existing staff that will soon be moving in.  So this owner/boss might say "everything is up for debate" as a way to indicate that everyone can be involved in the design/layout of the new building.

I'm wondering specifically if there isn't a less aggressive; more creative word or phrasing; I feel like 'debate' implies politics but for a creative project like a design or artwork it might be better to say something that gives a 'free and open collaboration' type feeling.

Comment: Remember to accept the best answer by clicking the checkmark next to it! Hope you found a good answer below! Cheers.

Comment: The opening paragraph doesn't match the remainder of your question or the answers in my reading. It seems to imply that a foundational belief or value is challenged, without which other goals and beliefs are uncertain. The term for that is a [basic belief](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_belief), but I'm not sure if that was @Derrick's intent.

Answer (score 3):

Everything is **on the table**

[Merriam Websters](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/on%20the%20table) gives this definition under 6.:

— on the table
: up for consideration or negotiation

```
the subject is not on the table
```

or

> **Nothing is off-limits**

[Collins dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/off-limits) has this to say about off limits.

> phrase 
> If an area or a place is off limits, you are not allowed to go
>   there. 
>  *A one-mile area around the wreck is still off limits*.
>  *These
>   establishments are off limits to ordinary citizen*s.

Answer (score 2):

- Nothing is set in stone yet
- All of the plans are up for discussion
- No plans have been solidified yet
- All of the plans are up in the air
- Nothing has been decided at the moment
- Everything is open for discussion

You can also add onto the sentence to encourage people to give input!

Comment: The phrase "up in the air" has a connotation of uncomfortable uncertainty for me.

Answer (score 2):

**”Nothing is set in stone”** is an applicable phrase. It implies that everything is amenable, and any part could be changed as needed.

Once something is set in stone (metaphorically or literally), it cannot be modified or moved easily.

Answer (score 1):

How about [... open for discussion](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/open%20for%20discussion) ?

> being a subject or issue that people can give their ideas, opinions, etc. about
> The issue is not open for discussion.

or

... up for [negotiation](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/negotiation)

> The important thing to remember is that negotiation is not necessarily adversarial; it often is a strategic process. The objective is to come up with an agreement that benefits all parties. Sometimes parties must give up some things, but this is indeed part of the negotiation, and giving something up frequently allows for gains in other areas of the negotiation.

or

... can be [brainstormed](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/brainstorm)

> to try to solve a problem or come up with new ideas by having a discussion that includes all members of a group
>
> to discuss a problem or issue and suggest solutions and ideas
>
> Students from Paris, Milan, Tokyo, and New York were invited to the Cambridge campus to brainstorm with MIT students on the marriage of couture and computer.
>
> Engineers are only beginning to brainstorm possible reasons that Polar Lander might have kept silent.

Comment: negotiation still sounds like a willingness to be talked into something rather than an invitation to open conversation to me. brainstorm has the right meaning, but requires some other rhetoric to establish the open invitational tone.

Answer (score 1):

What about "all assumptions will be questioned"?